# nested navigation SwitchNavigator>DrawerNavigator>TabsNavigator >StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-tabs

I have SwitchNavigator for login

after Switchnavigator it redirects to Drawernavigator.

inside Drawernavigator's home component i have Tabnavigator

Now, on tabs components on screen I want to got to a screen which should be out from Drawernavigator where i can popback to Drawernavigator's Tabnavigator.
How to achieve this ?
inside Drawernavigator 's home component i have a button.on click I want to go to a screen which should be out from Drawernavigator where i can popback to Drawernavigator's Tabnavigator.

How to achieve this ?